# how to add move image on touch event android?

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-imageview, move

This class has three Buttons Add table, Add chair and reset add table will add tablein second layout add chair will add chair image in second layout.Both button works but I want to move chair and table (`imageView`) in screen.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayList<String> mSelecetdItems = new ArrayList<>();
    public static final String SELECETD_ITEMS = "SELECETD_ITEMS";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public  void addtable(View v){
        this.mSelecetdItems.add("table");
        showSecondActivity();
    }
    public  void addchair(View v){
        this.mSelecetdItems.add("chair");
        showSecondActivity();
    }

    private void showSecondActivity() {
        Intent i = new Intent(this,Second.class);
        i.putStringArrayListExtra(SELECETD_ITEMS,this.mSelecetdItems);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        savedInstanceState.putStringArrayList(SELECETD_ITEMS , mSelecetdItems);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        this.mSelecetdItems = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList(SELECETD_ITEMS);
    }
}
```

This class has three Buttons Add table, Add chair and reset add table will add tablein second layout add chair will add chair image in second layout. I want to move table and chair in layout image.

**Second.java**

```
public class Second extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView iv;
    ImageView iv2;
    private int xDelta;
    private int yDelta;
    LinearLayoutCompat hall;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.second_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        hall = (LinearLayoutCompat) findViewById(R.id.hall_layout);
        Intent i = getIntent();

        ArrayList<String> selecetdItems = i.getStringArrayListExtra(MainActivity.SELECETD_ITEMS);
        for (String selecetdItem : selecetdItems) {
            if (selecetdItem.equals("table")) {
                addImageView(R.drawable.table, hall);
            } else if (selecetdItem.equals("chair")) {
                addImageView2(R.drawable.chair2, hall);
            }
        }
    }

    private void addImageView(int imageRes, LinearLayoutCompat hall) {
       iv = new ImageView(this);
        iv.setImageResource(imageRes);
        iv.setLayoutParams(new android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(250, 250));
        iv.setMaxHeight(180);
        iv.setMaxWidth(120);
        iv.setPadding(15,15,0,0);
        hall.addView(iv);
    }

    private void addImageView2(int imageRes, LinearLayoutCompat hall) {
         iv2 = new ImageView(this);
        iv2.setImageResource(imageRes);
        iv2.setLayoutParams(new android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(150, 150));
        iv2.setMaxHeight(30);
        iv2.setMaxWidth(30);

        iv2.setPadding(25,0,0,0);
        hall.addView(iv2);
    }
}
```

`activity_main.xml` This layout file has `ConstraintLayout` in Root.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.andiroot.restaurantbook.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#ff1e8622"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      >
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="495dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="64dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_addtbl"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
            android:text="Add Table"
            android:onClick="addtable"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_addchairs"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="addchair"
            android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
            android:text="Add Chair"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btn_addtbl"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/btn_addtbl" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_reset"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/btn_addchairs"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btn_addchairs"
            android:layout_marginTop="51dp"
            android:text="Reset" />
    </RelativeLayout>



</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

`activity_second.xml` This layout file has `LinearLayoutCompat`  in Root

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/hall_layout"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.andiroot.restaurantbook.Second">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/second_toolbar"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#ff1e8622"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">



    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
<!--
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/hall_layout2">
    </RelativeLayout>
-->
</android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>


</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    ImageView dishaIMG;
    RelativeLayout cropperLayout;
    float dX, dY;
    float windowWidth, windowHeight;

    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    windowHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
    windowWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

    cropperLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main2);

    dishaIMG = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_disha);


        dishaIMG.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            int width = dishaIMG.getLayoutParams().width;
            int height = dishaIMG.getLayoutParams().height;

            switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    dX = v.getX() - motionEvent.getRawX();
                    dY = v.getY() - motionEvent.getRawY();

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                    if (width == windowWidth && height == windowHeight) {


                    } else {
                        v.animate()
                                .x(motionEvent.getRawX() + dX)
                                .y(motionEvent.getRawY() + dY)
                                .setDuration(0)
                                .start();

                        if (motionEvent.getRawX() + dX + width > windowWidth) {
                            v.animate()
                                    .x(windowWidth - width)
                                    .setDuration(0)
                                    .start();
                        }
                        if (motionEvent.getRawX() + dX < 0) {
                            v.animate()
                                    .x(0)
                                    .setDuration(0)
                                    .start();
                        }
                        if (motionEvent.getRawY() + dY + height > windowHeight) {
                            v.animate()
                                    .y(windowHeight - height)
                                    .setDuration(0)
                                    .start();
                        }
                        if (motionEvent.getRawY() + dY < 0) {
                            v.animate()
                                    .y(0)
                                    .setDuration(0)
                                    .start();
                        }

                    }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```